# How can I extract only digits after a certain character?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

There is a node of the following content.

```
<item is_json_array="yes">
  <name>Дополнительная услуга Количество IP-адресов - 1 Шт (Размещение сервера 1U #817)</name>
  <amount>156.48</amount>
  <taxrate>0</taxrate>
  <taxamount>0.00</taxamount>
  <notaxamount>156.48</notaxamount>
</item>
```

I need to tear out of the `name` a substring containing only digits after the `#` sign. `817` to the first non-numeric character or the end of the string. numeric characters can be any number of

Comment: Use `substring-after(name,'#')` to get the '817)' string.

Comment: @zx485 without `)` symbol ?

Comment: For that you can use `substring-before(substring-after(name,'#'),')')`.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: @DanielHaley 1.0

Comment: @zx485 and if so  `some text#817some text` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you can use a combination of `substring-after()` and `translate()` to not only get the text after `#`, but also strip any unwanted characters.

Example...

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(.,'#'),translate(substring-after(.,'#'),'0123456789',''),'')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

A full working example can be seen here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMes/1